# parsing XML with Haskell with HXT

Tags: xml, haskell, arrows, hxt

I am trying to parse an XML file with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt. In the code below, I need to parse the inner elements with an extra parameter obtained from an attribute in the outer tag. But `i` is not available in the second line (second arrow?). How can I pass `i` to the `getTerminal`?

```
getSentence = atTag "s" >>>
  proc x -> do
    i   <- getAttrValue "id" -< x
    ts  <- listA (getTerminal i) <<< atTag "terminals"    -< x
    returnA -< Sentence { sid = i, terminals = ts }

...

getTerminal sid = atTag "t" >>> 
  proc x -> do
    i   <- getAttrValue "id"    -< x    
    lem <- getAttrValue "lemma" -< x
    returnA -< Terminal { lemma = lem, tid = nid i }
  where
    nid x = fromMaybe x (stripPrefix (sid ++ "_") x)
```

That is, `i` contains the value that I would like to pass to `getTerminal`.

Comment: What errors is your code causing? Or what is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Using `-<<` instead of `-<` makes local bindings available to the arrow:

```
getSentence = atTag "s" >>>
  proc x -> do
    i   <- getAttrValue "id" -< x
    ts  <- listA (getTerminal i) <<< atTag "terminals" -<< x
    returnA -< Sentence { sid = i, terminals = ts }
```

Note that `-<<` is implemented in terms of `app` from [`ArrowApply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowApply). For instance, syntactical awkwardness aside, its occurrence above could be replaced with:

```
    ts  <- app <<< listA . getTerminal *** atTag "terminals" -< (i, x)
```

The relevant arrows of *hxt* are instances of `ArrowApply`, so `-<<` can be used with them.